# using Fancybox with 2 ids the same

Tags: jquery

I have two fancybox iframes that are exactly the same and are both on the same page - they are just in different places (yes, they are both necessary). At present, they are referenced by this jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#index").fancybox({
        'width'             : 615,
        'height'            : 450,
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'autoDimensions'    : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
        'overlayColor'      : '#111',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
// index2   
$(function() {
    $("#index2").fancybox({
        'width'             : 615,
        'height'            : 450,
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'autoDimensions'    : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
        'overlayColor'      : '#111',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

I have called them #index and #index2. What is the syntax to combine these into the same function? Is it possible? I mean something like this:

```
$(function() {
$("#index" && "#index2").fancybox({
```

Comment: You could do `$("#index, #index2").fancybox({` see http://jsfiddle.net/T2cfX/ ... however @nebulae's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not familiar with fancybox, but if you can use class selectors instead of ids, you could give both elements the same class, say "fancy", and access them via

`$('.fancy').fancybox({...`

Answer (score 0):

If both fancy boxes are doing exactly the same thing can't you just use one and alter what page the iframe points to.

I don't think you could combine them because the code is saying how to specifically set up each index.

Comment: I need the fancybox to appear when clicked on from the page itself and from a div that slides in from the left but is usually hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can target both IDs by using this CSS like selector.

```
$('#index1, #index2')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QPquS/